# Performance of RAMFS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, performance, cache

I am profiling some computation (video transcoding) on large datasets. Since I did not want my results to be influenced by I/O time (the system I am using has old/slow spinning disks) I though that RAMFS would be the right approach.

I created a "cache" folder in my home as ramfs:

```
sudo mount ramfs -t ramfs ./cache/
```

I use this folder to save the input and output files for my video processing pipeline. **However**, it looks like there is some "caching" still going on between the disk and the RAM when reading files stored in the RAMFS which I think should not happen.
First I copy the input video file into the cache, notice that the file is around 1.5 GB, hence the need for RAMFS: https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/crowd_run_1080p50.y4m

```
cp crowd_run_1080p50.y4m ./cache/
```

When performing a transcoding operation, reading from the file I just copied and writing to RAMFS

```
perf stat -e minor-faults:u,major-faults:u  ~/bin/ffmpeg -i ~/cache/crowd_run_1080p50.y4m -c:v h264_qsv  -y ~/cache/out_qsv.mp4
```

perf still reports some major-faults:

```
        11,933      minor-faults:u                                              
           159      major-faults:u                                              

   3.588215239 seconds time elapsed
```

Running the same operation again shows no major faults and significantly faster completion time:

```
        11,955      minor-faults:u                                              
             0      major-faults:u                                              

   2.129031238 seconds time elapsed
```

Even more troubling if I flush the page cache of the OS

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

I will see major faults again. Why is that? I though that the whole file would stay in RAMFS together with the inodes and no flushing is possible from ramfs (unlike tmpfs that can swap). Why do I still see major faults? If I have to perform the same operation twice in order to get reliable results I might as well not use RAMFS, but I would like to understand what I am missing.

Comment: `ffmpeg` (and included libraries) is not on ramfs. it's in`~/bin`

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think that fetching the code would be that influential in the results Is there a way to force the OS to put specific binaries and libs in the page cache?

Comment: `apt-get install memlockd`

Answer (score 0):

The [`preload`](http://preload.sourceforge.net/) daemon can also helps in this situation. It runs in background *and learn* which programs and libraries are often in use. It then [`readahead`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) them on next boots for a faster launch.
As opposite to `memlockd` those files are not locked in RAM but read once after boot so their RAM space can be reused for something else if required, hence there is no guarantee of a faster launch.